# How to detect if a ball will collide with another, and the normal vector of the collision?

Tags: collision

So I have a 2D game involving balls (circles) colliding. I want to be able to detect if two balls will collide before it happens, and the normal vector of the collision if a collision is going to happen. Take a look at the below picture:

[image: Determining if balls will collide]

Essentially a normalized vector represented by the red arrow is what I am interested in knowing. How can I figure that out any frame most efficiently, given I know the following:

- The blue ball has a current initial velocity
- The ball ball is pulled down by a constant gravity
- The green ball does not move
- The sizes and location of both balls

Comment: Assuming you have a game loop that increments a time step, then at a given time, run an inner loop to simulate the time going forward out to a certain limit, and see if the balls will ever collide.

The normal vector is easy - it is just a radius of the green circle, from the center to the collision point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume:
r1 radius of green ball
(x1,y1) the position of green ball
r2 radius of blue ball
(x2,y2) the position of blue ball

The distance between the balls is
d^2 = (x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2
Collision occurs when
d^2 = (r1+r2)^2

The vector is just (x2-x1,y2-y1) when d=r1+r2